# Emplace empty vector into std::map()

Tags: c++, stl

How can I emplace an empty vector into a `std::map`? For example, if I have a `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>`, and I want `map[4]` to contain an empty `std::vector<int>`, what can I call?

Comment: Does `map[4]` exist in the first place?

Comment: Looks like XY problem, why do you need an empty vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the strictly-correct answer is indeed to use `std::piecewise_construct` as the first argument, followed by two tuples. The first represents the arguments to create the key (4), and the second represents the arguments to create the vector (empty argument set).

It would look like this:

```
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,   // signal piecewise construction
            std::make_tuple(4),         // key constructed from int(4)
            std::make_tuple());         // value is default constructed
```

Of course this looks unsightly, and other alternatives will work. They may even generate no more code in an optimised build:

This one notionally invokes default-construction and move-assignment, but it is likely that the optimiser will see through it.

```
map.emplace(4, std::vector<int>());
```

This one invokes default-construction followed by copy-assignment. But again, the optimiser may well see through it.

```
map[4] = {};
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think OP realized what they were doing when they said `emplace` in the post. The later sentences reveal the problem they're actually trying to solve. That said, if OP really meant we should only use `emplace`, then I agree that this answer is "strictly-correct".

Comment: @AndyG simple questions about c++ are like that I find. The simpler the question, the more intricate and nuanced becomes the answer.

Comment: It seems they really did mean to use emplace!

Answer (score 4):

If you use `operator[](const Key&)`, the map will automatically emplace a *value-initialized* (i.e. in the case of `std::vector`, *default-constructed*) value if you access an element that does not exist. See here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

(Since C++ 11 the details are a tad more complicated, but in your case this is what matters).

That means if your map is empty and you do `map[4]`, it will readily give you a reference to an empty (default-constructed) vector. Assigning an empty vector is unnecessary, although it may make your intent more clear.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/g/rnfW7g

Answer (score 2):

To ensure an empty vector is placed at position 4, you may simply attempt to `clear` the vector at position 4.

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> my_map;
my_map[4].clear();
```

As others have mentioned, the indexing operator for `std::map` will construct an empty value at the specified index if none already exists. If that is the case, calling `clear` is redundant. However, if a `std::vector<int>` does already exist, the call to `clear` serves to, well, clear the vector there, resulting in an empty vector.

This may be more efficient than my previous approach of assigning to `{}` (see below), because we probably plan on adding elements to the vector at position 4, and we don't pay any cost of new allocation this way. Additionally, if previous usage of `my_map[4]` indicates future usage, then our new vector will likely be eventually resized to the nearly the same size as before, meaning we save on reallocation costs.

---

#### Previous approach:

just assign to `{}` and the container should properly construct an empty vector there:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> my_map;
my_map[4] = {};
std::cout << my_map.size() << std::endl; // prints 1
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TMATnUU8JM4sDSqI)

Edit: As Jodocus mentions, if you know that the `std::map` doesn't already contain a `vector` at position 4, then simply attempting to access the vector at that position will default-construct one, e.g.:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> my_map;
my_map[4]; // default-constructs a vector there
```

Comment: Funnily enough, it suffices to write `my_map[4];`.

Comment: @Jodocus: Yes, as a consequence of how the indexing operator works. It's not always so obvious though. I've had a couple of my team members caught out on it. Edit: good point though, I'll add that in.

Comment: @Jodocus: Also I suppose this is safer since likely one doesn't want to check that there is nothing there to begin with; if you want an empty vector there then it's best to assign anyway since there might already be a non-empty vector there.

Comment: I would prefer `my_map[4].clear();` than assignation.

Comment: @Jarod42: Hm, yeah that's definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the simplest possible solution? `std::map[4] = {};`.

In modern C++, this should do what you want with no or at least, very little, overhead.

If you must use `emplace`, the best solution I can come up with is this:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> map;
map.emplace(4, std::vector<int>());
```

Comment: Simples possible solution is `map[4];` without assignment

Answer (score -1):

Use piecewise_construct with std::make_tuple:

```
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(4), std::make_tuple());
```

We are inserting an empty vector at position 4.

And if there is a general case like, emplacing a vector of size 100 with 10 filled up then:

```
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(4), std::make_tuple(100, 10));
```

`piecewise_construct`: This constant value is passed as the first argument to construct a pair object to select the constructor form that constructs its members in place by forwarding the elements of two tuple objects to their respective constructor.

Comment: IMHO this is overly complicated, and OP specifically asked for an empty vector.

Comment: I will explain it a bit more.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but if you changed the second `std::make_tuple` to `std::make_tuple()`, then your code will actually solve the problem OP asked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!!